# Add operation on pointer

Tags: c, pointers

```
int a[3];
int *j;
a[0]=90;
a[1]=91;
a[2]=92;
j=a;
printf("%d",*j);
printf("%d",&a[0])
printf("%d",&a[1]);
printf("%d",*(j+2));
```

here the pointer variable `j` is pointing to `a[0]`,which is 90;and address of `a[0]` is -20 is on my machine. So `j` is holding -20.
And the address of `a[1]` is -18. So to get next variable I should use `*(j+2)`. because `j+2` will result in -18. but this is actually going on. To access `a[1]`. I have to use `*(j+1)`. but `j+1=-19`. Why is `j+1` resulting in -18 ?

Comment: `and address of a[0] is -20...` - the address is not going to be a negative number... addresses are unsigned.

Comment: you assigned the integer pointer j the value of the integer array address a, which is a constant integer pointer.  a[0] is equivalent to *(a+0), which clearly is an integer, not an integer pointer.

Comment: `*(x+y)` is exactly equivalent to `x[y]` (or `y[x]`). So to print `a[1]`, you want `*(j + 1)` (or just `j[1]`).

Answer (score 3):

Addresses are unsigned.  You're printing them as if they were an `int`, but they're not an `int`.  Use `"%p"` as the format specifier.  That's how you print the address of a pointer.

Additionally, pointer arithmetic is different than the arithmetic you are used to. Internally, adding one to a pointer `p` increments the address by `sizeof *p` bytes, i.e., it increments the to the next object.

This is convenient as it saves the programmer from having to always use `sizeof` when performing arithmetic on a pointer (rarely do you actually want to increment by something other than `sizeof *p`. When you do, you cast to a `char*` first.)

Answer (score 0):

pointer addition is not same as simple addition.

It depends on what type of variable the pointer is pointing.

In your case it's an int whose size is machine dependent (you can check of doing sizeof(int)).

So when adding a number to pointer like `(j+i)` it internally converts to `(j+i*sizeof(datatype))` so when you type `(j+2)` the address is increased the 4 times (assuming int to be 2 bytes) which is not the intended result.

`(j+1)` will give you the right result (it's like saying point to the next element of int type of data)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the pointer logic works on the basis of the pointer type since integer pointer type moves by size of integer on your machine it moves by the 2 bytes on your machine so p+1 = p+(sizeof(type of pointer))

Answer (score 0):

`*(x+y)` is always exactly equivalent to `x[y]` (or `y[x]`). So to print `a[1]`, you want `*(j + 1)` (or just `j[1]`). Note that, in `a[1]`, `a` is converted to a pointer ... there's no difference between the way `a` is handled and the way `j` is handled here.